# Kotlin: Merge three lists into one with selected data from three lists

Tags: android, kotlin

I have to create a new list merged with three others lists and use it as the Detail list.
This is how it looks like:

```
@Parcelize
data class Detail(
val photoId: Int,        //Photo
val photoTitle: String,  //Photo
val albumTitle: String,  //Album
val username: String,    //User
val email: String,       //User
val phone: String,       //User
val url: String.         //Photo
) : Parcelable
```

I assigned the model to each property. A property named photoId requires an id field from the Photo, photoTitle requires a photoTitle from Photo, albumTitle requires a title from the Album and so on. I know how to do it by Filter based on two lists, but no have idea how it make with three lists.
This is my earlier solution for two lists:

```
if (albumsList.isNotEmpty() && photosList.isNotEmpty()) {
                                                                                                      //Merging the lists of RawAlbum and
        val albumsById: Map<Int, RawAlbum> = albumsList.associateBy { it.id }                        // RawPhoto in the one ListItem list.

         itemList = photosList.filter { albumsById[it.id] != null }.map { photosList ->
             albumsById[photosList.id]?.let { albumsList ->
                 ListItem(albumsList.id, albumsList.title, photosList.title, photosList.thumbnailUrl)
             }!!
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get all unique items from the three lists into a single list? You might try Kotlin Standard Library's [union](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/union.html) operator.

Probably do something like `((list1 union list2) union list3)`

Comment: Thank you for your idea, but I created my own solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very easy answer to my question. Of course code needs some save improvements, but works. I don't need a new list in this solution, it goes straight to the required model.

```
 private fun setDetail(id: Int) {
    if (albumsList.isNotEmpty() && photosList.isNotEmpty() && userList.isNotEmpty()) {

        if (id != null) {
            var photo = photosList[id]
            var user = userList[id]
            var album = albumsList[id]

            var detail = Detail(photo.id, photo.title, user.username, album.title, user.email, user.phone, photo.url)
            Timber.e(detail.toString())

            onDetailsFragment(detail)

        }
    }
}
```